# Best way to add spell check for react app?

Tags: reactjs, textarea, spell-checking

What is the best way to add spell check (with custom suggestion menu) to react app? For example to `textarea` element. I know that it's possible with the server-side and with vanilla javascript. So what's the best way? Maybe you have some solutions?

Comment: the same as with vanilla js

Comment: and the reward for the best answer goes to the @Sulthan

Comment: I have actually answered exactly what you asked. If you know how to do it with vanilla javascript or server side, it's exactly the same in React.
From your other comments it seems you are more interested in autocompletion functionality? Do you have already a completion API ready? Still, not very different from vannila-js. Maybe you should ask a more specific question? What did you try and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at docs: [Official React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#html-attributes).

If for basic `html/vanillajs` you would use a textarea like:

`<textarea spellcheck="true" />`

In `React`, you would use:
`<textarea spellCheck="true" />`

Comment: I expanded my question. I am interested in solutions with a custom suggestion menu.

Comment: Have a look at this [Tutorial on autocomplete](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/resources/ui-and-ux-patterns/in-depth/autocomplete/tutorials/autocomplete-textarea/). Is this the same with what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: no, example is - https://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/

Comment: i want to disable the action button if there is errror in spelling

Answer (score 0):

Here , the spellcheck attribute is true, so it will give the red underline if we write something wrong in content.

To remove that we can set the spellcheck attribute to be "false".
instead of

```
 <h1 className="heading" contentEditable="true" spellCheck="true">Hello</h1>
```

we can make it

```
 <h1 className="heading" contentEditable="true" spellCheck="false">Hello</h1>
```